# XNA - vertex streams?

Tags: xna, hlsl

Would someone provide/point me to an explanation of or tutorial on using multiple vertex streams in HLSL and XNA? I'm interested in how they're stored/accessed by the GPU, advantages of or uses for streams in custom shaders, etc.

I've seen a few examples on using multiple vertex streams for instanced geometry, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the underlying mechanism.

**Update**

If I have a vertex shader which accepts two parameters [(borrowed from this tutorial](http://www.float4x4.net/index.php/2010/06/hardware-instancing-in-xna/))

```
InstancingVSoutput InstancingVS(InstancingVSinput input, float4x4 instanceTransform : TEXCOORD0, float4 color : TEXCOORD4)
{
 InstancingVSoutput output;
 float4 pos = input.Position;
 pos = mul(pos, transpose(instanceTransform));
 pos = mul(pos, WVP);
 output.Position = pos;
 output.Color = color;
 return output;
}
```

It seems from the example that I pulled this from that `instanceTransform` and `input` are pulled from separate streams. However, in this case, the `input` stream is a list of six vertices, and the `instanceTransform` comes from a stream of a much larger number of elements, consisting of translation matrices. This is supposed to be used for instanced geometry.

I'm confused about how many times this shader gets executed - is it VertexBuffer0.VertexCount*VertexBuffer1.VertexCount? The problem with this kind of thing is that, once someone's figured it out, they don't bother contributing a well-written document back to the community detailing their discovery.

Argh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one else has chimed in yet, I'll give it a go :-) this is a great thread on the apphub forums about Vertex Streams:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/46229/276901.aspx

from one of the answers:

> The gist is this: different streams
>   can have different data layouts, and
>   your VertexDeclaration determines what
>   data gets pulled from what stream. 
>   So, for instance, you could have one
>   buffer that stores all your positions
>   and one buffer which stores all your
>   colors, and you could set those to
>   different streams; alternatively you
>   could munge them into a single stream,
>   but this isn't always convenient.

Hope it helps ;-)